# children height 100% without setting parent fixed height

Tags: html, css, height

I have a container `div` that contains 2 children `divs`: the first one, stick to his father's left border, contains a list of buttons while the second one contains the content. Long story short, it works like a tab navigator, with the buttons on the left.

The problem I have is with the buttons container height, that I'd like it to be 100% of his parent `div`. I don't want to give a fixed height to the container div, because I want the container to change accordingly to his content height..

As you can see in the fiddle below, the `ul` right border is not touching the container bottom edge..

here's some code

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="buttons">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">button 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">button 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">button 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">button 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        asdasdasdasdas<br>
        ...
        asdasdasdasdas<br>                       
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#buttons{
    background: lightgray;
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    height: 100%
}
#content{
    padding: 15px;
    float: left;
}
#container{
    /*-- adding fixed height here, works*/
    /*height: 300px;*/
    display: inline-block;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

**FIDDLE**

- what I've currently done -->http://jsfiddle.net/BeNdErR/kVcds/
- the result I'd like to achieve, without the fixed height --> http://jsfiddle.net/BeNdErR/kVcds/2/
- another case that I'd like to be covered: content shorter than the buttons div --> http://jsfiddle.net/BeNdErR/kVcds/8/

Any idea or solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance, best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using absolutely positioning the #buttons div within the parent.

For this, first declare relative positioning on the parent

```
#container {
    position:relative;
    min-height:200px;/* if you can reliably set a minimum height */
}

#buttons {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:150px;
}

#content {
    margin-left:150px;
}
```

Because the absolutely positioned button elements are now out of the page flow, you can add a margin equal to the width of the #buttons div to the #content div so that it still is in the right place.

See the updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kVcds/3/

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but I didn't consider this case: http://jsfiddle.net/BeNdErR/kVcds/7/ where the content is shorter than the buttons div

Comment: Can you simply add a `min-height` to the content wrapper, then?

Answer (score -2):

You might want to refer to this links. It will likely get you what you want, but it's not as simple as you would have probably have wanted it.

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

Hope this helps!